# How can I bulk edit variations in woocommerce?

Tags: plugins

I’m setting up a store selling art prints that have
multiple canvas/paper types, and ten different print sizes for 200 photos. 
All prices on all sizes with specified canvas-type are
the same from image to image, but they have to be entered one at a time
on the variations drop-down admin. That means thousands of entries if it
has to be done for each variation on each product. And then if there’s a
price increase, thousands of edits instead of just a few dozen.

The “Bulk Editing” feature for variations changes all the prices of ALL the variations.
(That is, if you "Bulk Edit" the price, all variations-- small, medium,
large -- end up with the same price.)

If you’re managing any real number of products with multiple variations and prices
that need to be changed, this is a real shortcoming of woocommerce.

Is there a way to batch edit variations for multiple products, or create a product template that would have the same variations for prices with different sizes?

Comment: Something that may help is 'Linking possible variations' which automatically creates all the possible variations available. It is mentioned further down the page here http://docs.woothemes.com/document/product-variations I've not used it so can't elaborate further sorry but hopefully this helps.

Comment: http://webpresencepartners.com/2012/09/19/a-free-simple-woocommerce-csv-importer/ This is the free alternative to the $99 plugin you are referring to. You are welcome. :)

Comment: Try WOOBE: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-bulk-editor/ - its free for editing prices

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found for mass updating variations that all have different prices is to get an extension / plug in that allows you to export the data to a spreadsheet file format, then make the desired changes to the file using a spreadsheet program, and then import the modified spreadsheet.  The Woo Commerce team sells such a plugin, but the price is kind of steep... it's almost a hundred bucks. If anyone has a cheaper solution, I'm all ears.

Comment: Welcome to the WordPress StackExchange community! Please place your responses to other users in a comment in the appropriate location rather than in your answer (i.e. respond to Jules in a comment on his answer).

Comment: Like mentioned above, we have developed a version that you can bulk edit right in your dashboard and its much much less then that other one. You can find it here http://bit.ly/1blYEsa